# Implement the application between the calling on the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-2.0

I hope my application(e.g: appA) can call Third-party application(e.g: appB),When appB is finished running,I hope can get

appS's running result(success 、fail or error) and the result tell appA,go back appA then continue to run appA,Now I know I

can use the method that it's openURL.but, when I called appB after,I don't know how to go back appA.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API for calling an arbitrary third-party application.  Also, apps on iOS don't finish running at any particular time if they support being put in the background.